# Android: Spinner without blank rows

Tags: android

I have a spinner with Horoscopes, but between each entry of the horoscopes there is a blank row, which I don't want. How can I delete it?

My code:

```
strings.xml

<string-array name="horoscope_array">
        <item>Aquarius</item>
        <item>Pisces</item>
        <item>Aries</item>
        <item>Taurus</item>
        <item>Gemini</item>
        <item>Cancer</item>
        <item>Leo</item>
        <item>Virgo</item>
        <item>Libra</item>
        <item>Scorpius</item>
        <item>Sagitarius</item>
        <item>Capricorn</item>
    </string-array>

<string name="horoscope_prompt">Choose a Horoscope</string>
```

On my `layout.xml` I have:

```
<Spinner
android:layout_height="35dp"
android:id="@+id/spinner1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:entries="@array/horoscope_array"
android:textColor="@color/orange"
android:prompt="@string/horoscope_prompt" />
```

Comment: Can you show the screenshot ? And did you try removing `android:layout_height="35dp"` ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna it's not possible to remove it because then I have an exception

Comment: How ? what exception ? can you post that as well ? and screenshot ? Is it all the related codes you posted.